# Symfony 3 - Add routes from bundles dynamically by Loader class

Tags: php, symfony

Newbie from Symfony framework here. I'm trying to go trough [How to Create a custom Route Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html) Cookbook section and make routing autoloading working in my bundle but without a success. Here are all related to this topic files:

**Loader:**

```
namespace Notimeo\CoreBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class AdvancedLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();

        $resource = '@NotimeoCoreBundle/Resources/config/import_routing.yml';
        $type     = 'yaml';

        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource, $type);

        $collection->addCollection($importedRoutes);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return 'advanced_extra' === $type;
    }
}
```

**DependencyInjection:**

```
namespace Notimeo\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class CoreExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
    }

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

**src/Notimeo/CoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:**

```
notimeo_core_routes:
    resource: .
    type: advanced_extra
```

**src/Notimeo/CoreBundle/Resources/config/import_routing.yml:**

```
# homepage
homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: CoreBundle:Base:index
```

**src/Notimeo/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:**

```
services:
    routing.loader.advanced_loader:
        class: Notimeo\CoreBundle\Routing\AdvancedLoader
        tags:
            - { name: routing.loader }
```

Getting `No route found for "GET /"` error...

(using Symfony 3)

---

**UPDATE**:

Well... it's working if I will move content of **src/Notimeo/CoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:**
to
**app/config/routing.yml**.

But... why? Why I can't put all contents in my bundle?

Answer (score 1):

you can put all the contents in `src/Notimeo/CoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` just make sure to include it in `app/config/routing.yml`

just add the below lines in `app/config/routing.yml`

_

```
my_custom_route:
    resource: "@NotimeoCoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```